# Estimating costs to implement a permissioned blockchain

Tags: permissioned-chain

I'm trying to ascertain what inputs and costs would be associated with implementing a permissioned blockchain like Hyperledger or Quorum. So far I have come up with the hardware costs (i.e servers) and employees with the skillsets necessary (i.e developers). What other inputs or costs would need to be considered?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is very hard, because we have to understand whole algorithm and maths behind this coins and implement into any system level language. we need full time developing team for it.

Following things are inevitable

- Budget for Marketing
- High Level Cloud Server configurations with auto backup
- Team of Skilled Developers
- IOC Marketing
- Security
- AML Anti-Money Laundering implementations and legal stuffs
- KYC implement KYC API
- Registering New coin in various platforms and approval

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you've already decided upon and set up an appropriate legal structure for your company (partnership, co-op, LLC, etc.) and have the requisite documents (shareholders agreements, employment contracts, etc.)

Some stuff off the top of my head...

Servers, IMHO, aren't a cost of implementing; they are a cost of deployment. Then again, the devs still need to have machines to dev on. So this stuff pertains only to the implementation part (which may run concurrently with other corporate activities).

For infrastructure, depending on project size, you may have things like

- communication (e-mail, chat, VCS, Internet, phones, library/access to research, etc.)
- space and renovations/inspection
- furniture and basic amenities (Kitchen? TV? Plants?)
- hardware (servers, as you mentioned, but also computers for developers, network infrastructure, telecoms, power distribution/backup/generation/balancing)

Depending on your outfit, you may also need to budget in services -- in-house or out-sourced -- to maintain this basic infrastructure:

- building maintenance
- dev-ops
- sysadmins
- systems maintenance (maintaining off-site backups, replacement parts, etc.)
- tech support
- consultants/external review and auditing
- insurance for employees, directors, and property; specialized insurance for your technology, if applicable

Employees (and the associated expenses like salary, insurance, retirement plan payments, stock option plans, health plans, vacation pay, travel, training, sick pay, etc.):

- Developers
- computer scientists
- Sysadmins
- Dev-ops
- QA
- Requirements engineers
- HR/payroll
- Building security (for securing building + data)

Not directly contributing to the development, but you may also need (depending on your jurisdiction, organization, and your own competency at various disciplines)

- Legal specialists for different regions (types of specialists will vary depending on what you're doing -- e.g., you might need IP specialists, contract lawyers, securities lawyers, property lawyers, etc.) for your particular blockchain technology
- Auditor
- Accountant
- Notary

Other miscellaneous on-going costs during dev cycle:

- Rent/mortgage
- Interest payments
- Banking fees
- Utilities (HVAC, gas, water, etc.)

And, of course, the scary "something bad just happened" expenses (like your office space caught on fire and you need to spend time/money to get rolling again).